# What are the "protocols" on my Brother printer?

Tags: networking, ftp, printing, printer, brother-printer

I have a Brother DCP-L2530DW series printer and I was wondering whether it would be possible to scan to a network folder (FTP or CIFS/SMB).

I see that there are some "protocols" available on the web admin page, includnig one called `FTP Client` and `FTP Server`.

[image]

**What are these? How can I configure the FTP client section on the printer?**

The Scan entry is quite empty and does not immediately offer to scan to a network location (I do not know whether this is possible, but since there is apparently an FTP client...)

Comment: Have you tried reading the fine manual?

Comment: @DavidPostill: yes, I have tried reading the fine manual (in French, which is quite an accomplishment for something related to computers https://download.brother.com/welcome/doc100802/cv_mfcl2750dw_fre_oug_a.pdf) and the said fine manual does not, unfortunately, mention what these FTP Client and Server entries are. It also, alas, mentions some elements which are not on my web interface - from which I infer that they are not available. But since FTP Server and Client are there, I permitted myself to raise the above question. It is also possible that I missed them, in which case I will be sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bizarre how the manuals in different languages contain different information. In the Dutch manual, the explanation is there, but not in the French or English versions. You already seem to have some problems with French, so I will try to give a short translation of  the Dutch. Terminology may be a bit off; I don't have this printer.

1. Start the webbrowser
2. Select scanning
3. Select scanning to FTP/Network
4. Select the option FTP and submit
5. click the Scan to FTP/Network profile menu in the left navigation menu
6. Select a profile
7. Type a name in the field Profile Name
8. In Host address, fill-in a host name (max 64 chars) or an IP address
9. You may change the port number
10. Fill-in a user name
11. Fill in the password
12. Fill in the directory on the FTP server; do not start with a slash or backslash
13. select a filename
14. Check the other options there as well
15. select submit

Comment: I am French :), what I meant is that computer documentation in French is cumbersome as the namings are always different from everybody else. I do not have the tab you mention ("scan to FTP" - I only have "Scan to PC"), so I guess that despite having the possibility to choose (check) `FTP Server` or `FTP Client` in the "Protocols" information, it is simply not supported (and the "Protocols" part is basically useless and misleading). Thanks a lot for the translation, though!

Comment: The manual is for a number of models, and indeed it says something like "depending on your model".

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well. What really bothers me is that the "Protocol" page allows me to enable or disable protocols (FTP, client and server) and this apparently means nothing. Well, it is a learning lesson at least. Thanks.